# Why are kc_locale and UI lang switch not working?

Tags: keycloak

A `test-web` application links to the keycloak reset-credentials page:

```
http://localhost:9990/auth/realms/test/login-actions/reset-credentials?client_id=test-web&kc_locale=en
```

We use the default `keycloak` theme and run on the Keycloak docker image `11.0.2`.

The UI works fine, but the `kc_locale` is not respected and also the UI language switch on the keycloak page does not work. The UI switch does update the `kc_locale` in the URL but the UI keeps showing the same language. There are 2 languages configured for the realm (`de` and `en`). No matter which of them I set as default, the UI always shows `de`.

In the account console the language switch as well as the `kc_locale` both actually change the language. But on the reset-credentials page it is not working.

After following the link of the email to the update-password page, on this page the UI switch and `kc_locale` work fine.

```
http://localhost:9990/auth/realms/test/login-actions/required-action?execution=UPDATE_PASSWORD&client_id=test-web&tab_id=fZIAUd_jiPc
```

After changing the language via the Account Console or on the update-password page, the reset-credentials page also shows the newly selected language, but the lang-switch on the page itself does not work.

What could be the reason for it?

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution found?

Comment: We could not solve it. My guess is, that it has something to do with the csrf tokens or a similar mechanism. It basically only works if the link is called from within keycloak. We redesigned our flows so that we do no longer have a custom login page but use the keycloak login page (with a custom theme) from where users can find the link to the reset page.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve gone through the versions to find out when this behavior changed. 8.0.2 respects the query parameters, but 9.0.0 till 14.0.0 don’t.

I did a workaround that fixed this issue
at template.ftl

```
<a class="${properties.kcLocaleItemClass!}" href="${l.url}">${l.label} </a>
```

instead of changing the href to l.locale
i added onClick event and then passed a function that sets a cookie for the selected language before changing href to l.url

```
<li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a tabindex="0" onclick="changeLocale(`${l.label}`, `${l.url}`)">${l.label}</a></li>
```

```
function changeLocale(label, url) {
if (label == ‘English’) {
document.cookie = “KEYCLOAK_LOCALE=en”;
} else {
document.cookie = “KEYCLOAK_LOCALE=fr”;
}
window.location.href = url
}
```

Comment: The above solution by Abdelhameed worked for us, with one caveat: we had to specify a root cookie path, else Keycloak's own cookie would get precedence. Like so:
`document.cookie = "KEYCLOAK_LOCALE=en;path=/";`

Answer (score 2):

Seems that there is an issue in keycloak server since version 9: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-11-0-3-does-not-respect-kc-locale-parameter/6529

Which may be caused by changes introduced with https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-9632

The locale selection mechanism has been reworked in that cause, however probably breaking the original selection mechanism.