# Keycloak ui_locales is ignored on requesting password reset link

Tags: keycloak

I am passing a chosen language from my web app into the keycloak login ui with `keyCloakClient.createLoginUrl({locale: locale})` which correctly redirects me to: `https://localhost/auth/realms/../protocol/openid-connect/auth?....&ui_locales=it`. This shows me the content correctly in locale `it`.

For the password-reset link shown in the login form, I also added `ui_locales=it` to the url, which redirects me to: `https://localhost/auth/realms/../login-actions/reset-credentials?....&ui_locales=it`. This also shows me the content correctly in locale `it`.

**Problem:**

When I add `ui_locales=it` to the submission url for submitting the reset-password-request (`${url.loginAction?no_esc}` in `login-reset-password.ftl`, that generates the url `https://localhost/auth/realms/../login-actions/reset-credentials?..`), and I submit the form, I land on: `https://localhost/auth/realms/../login-actions/authenticate?execution=...`. This suddenly has no `ui_locales` in the url, and the content is therefore not translated in locale `it`.

To test if there are any magic redirections, i logged the network with preserve-log enabled. It shows only one new entry after clicking the reset-password-request button: `https://localhost/auth/realms/../login-actions/reset-credentials?...&ui_locales=it`.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The same issue happens when submitting the login form with wrong credentials, to the action url (`${url.loginAction?no_esc}`) with appended `&ui_locales=it`.

It seems that locale query parameter is buggy since a while see [Why are kc_locale and UI lang switch not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64517990/why-are-kc-locale-and-ui-lang-switch-not-working). According to https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/release_notes/, in `9.0` was a change for locale, and was reverted in `9.0.1`. Since then, there was no new change for locale. I am using `12.0.4`.

**Cookie approach:**

I created the Cookie `KEYCLOAK_LOCALE` with JS on my React Login GUI, passing the locale value from the URL. It works only until a user logs in the very first time. Because then, Keycloak somehow sets the same Cookie with httpOnly, so that I can't read/write the Cookie value anymore with JS. So I can't overwrite the Cookie value on a new login, and I can't read the Cookie value to sync it with the React GUI localization.

- **Working usecase**: Choose language in App -> redirect to Keycloak login -> set `KEYCLOAK_LOCALE` Cookie with value from the url (Keycloak & GUI language stay in sync now) -> go back to App -> change language in App -> redirect to Keycloak login -> Keycloak language can be updated over the Cookie with js **because Cookie is not httpOnly**.
- **Not working usecase**: Choose language in App -> redirect to Keycloak login -> set `KEYCLOAK_LOCALE` Cookie with value from the url (Keycloak & GUI language stay in sync now) -> login -> Keycloak updates the Cookie to be httpOnly -> redirect back to App happens -> logout -> change language in App -> redirect to Keycloak login -> Keycloak language can't be updated over the Cookie with js **because Cookie is httpOnly**.

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by setting the cookie in `template.ftl` manually before reloading the page.

let me know if you need more support.

````
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        let locales = 'ui_locales';

        document.getElementById("lang-link").addEventListener("click", function() {
            let switchTo = ...
            document.cookie = 'KEYCLOAK_LOCALE=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;'
            document.cookie = 'KEYCLOAK_LOCALE='+ switchTo;
            // change the language
            const currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
            currentUrl.searchParams.set(locales, switchTo);
            document.location.href = currentUrl;
        });
    });
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I've added this snippet to my code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
                    let parameters = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
                    let locale = parameters.get('ui_locales');
                    if (locale != null) {
                        let [language, country] = locale.split('-');
                        document.cookie = "KEYCLOAK_LOCALE=" + language + "; path=/;";
                    }
                }
            })();
        </script>
```

Now on login page load i set `KEYCLOAK_LOCALE` from `ui_locales` parameter

Comment: I already have such an approach like I described in `Cookie approach:`. But like I described, there is a `Not working usecase`. I wonder if the described usecase works in your case?